# !important declarations in media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I am currently using zurb foundation. Using the below code, the body always has the background color red, no matter what the size of the view port,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
.body {background: red;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) {
.body {background: blue;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) {
.body {background: green;}
}
```

Only when I add !important declarations, does the body color change color as the viewport size increases

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
.body {background: red;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) {
.body {background: blue !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) {
.body {background: green !important;}
}
```

This doesn't seem to be the correct way to do things, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding minimum and maximum width

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90.062em){
   .body {background: red;}
}
```

Comment: Also make sure you're not overriding another .body class somewhere else in your css. You'd require !important to accomplish that.